# Sending a request to microservice

Tags: jar, microservices

I am taking out a part of a service from a monolith application and creating a microservice. So I have a monolith application and a microservice(MS).

Problem Statement-
I need to communicate with microservice via REST APIs. So my monolith will divert some specific API calls to microservice.
Now while communication, do I need to map the params of microservice in my monolith?

Creating a jar seems to be a bad idea as it violates the fundamental principles of microservice being independently deployable.

Suppose a create user API is sent to MS, with 
- name and 
- address 
as params

Now in MS side the param names are 
- nm
- prms

Ques1. Do I need to map MS params in monolith? 
Ques2. or should I create a new service in between which will take care of this
Ques3. or should I send the params without mapped and let MS parse and filter out params from the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets discuss each approach

**Ques1. Do I need to map MS params in monolith?**

When you break your monolithic application , you should be doing in parts . As you mentioned you have taken out one part and converted into microservice. Your monolithic and microservices are running side by side. You can map the parameters in monolithic application as long as your microservice is independent. At one point your monolithic application will be completed migrated so your each microservice will be accepting parameters on its own with out monolithic application. Considering this if your microservice can do this then it should be ok. This approach is good if you are still doing A/B testing and want to send say 25% requests to new service and rest are still being covered by your monolithic application. If there is any problem you simple turn all traffic back to monolithic.

**Ques2. or should I create a new service in between which will take care of this**

This service will play as your gateway. If you will be adding more services later then this service will be more useful than passing the parameters from monotlithic to microservices. I would prefer this approach , since after your microservices are completed you will be needing gateway service anyway and in this case you have it done already and this service knows about all the microservices and removing monolithic from picture won't break anything.

**Ques3. should I send the params without mapped and let MS parse and filter out params from the request**

I dont understand this part but make your microservice in a way that input parameters given to it are enough to complete the operation without microservice doing something additional

Comment: Thanks Imran for your time. The only concern I have now is param mapping in my monolith. 

Is it necessary to map my params in monolith if in case param name differs in monolith and microservice

Comment: I am not aware of complete picture. But you can do if you want to . As long as you are able to get rid of these params in future and directly calling service from client. If you could share your architecture diagram that would be easy

Comment: 1. So I got an API call to monolith, what monolith will do is divert the API call to MS

2. Suppose, the API call to monolith was **POST /users**  `name: Alex, age: 19`
 

3. What monolith will internally do is map(resolve) the `name` and `age` param-names with the MS param-names like username = name and userage = age

4. Now the API call from monolith to MS will be, *POST /users* `username: Alex`, userage: 19`

PS: its not architecture level doubt, just IPC related doubt. The above solution seems to be not correct is because the synchronous request/response makes it  tightly coupled.

Comment: You are right. Better create new service or intercept the request in gateway and pass it to microservice or monolithic app. Mapping from Monolith is tight coupling. Normally when we have monolith and micorservices sitting side by side, we deal them according to what's required in them rather pass through the request from either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Design your MS independent of the Monolith.  That is to say your MS's API signatures should follow good standard REST practices, including naming conventions for URL paths and param names.

Your Monolith will gave to call the MS using the MS's API signature.  If the monolith calls a param "name" and your MS calls it "username", then so be it... your Monolith will just be calling the MS as if it was any other external API and it will have to user the appropriate param names and security of that API.